# Force.com IDE takes forever to save JSON static resource

Tags: force.com, ide, static-resources, platform-bug

In my package I have a JSON file served as Static Resource. Whenever I change and save this file from a current version of the Force.com IDE it takes forever until its finally saved. I idles around 23% for 10 minutes.

I have no idea why.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I was using a Static Resource as a JSON file. I ended up using TextWrangler (Mac) to cleanse the text, which I then pasted into the file.  That solved the problem for me.

1. Create a new file in TextWrangler
2. Paste in the text (JSON)
3. Go to View => Text Display => Show Invisibles
4. Go to Text => Zap Gremlins
5. Select "Replace With" and enter a space as the replacement character
6. Click Zap
7. In my case, this operation replaces a bunch of characters that looked like space with a "real" space
8. Copy the text and paste it into your static resource
9. Save. It should save immediately.

Comment: Sounded like a solution that just has to work...But actually changes nothing for my problem. Followed your steps exactely :-(